# how to work with self join in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have 2 tables in sql

```
1. SELECT TOP 1000 [UserId]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[Password]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[Password_Expiry]
      ,[Modified]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Privileges]
  FROM [Paramount].[dbo].[UserProfile]



2. SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
      ,[UserId]
      ,[ClockInClockOutTypeId]
      ,[CreatedDate]
  FROM [Paramount].[dbo].[ClockInClockOut]
```

i need to retrieve data form both tables like-

```
[UserName]| Date [CreatedDate]|[CreatedDate](just time in) as TimeIn | [CreatedDate](just Time Out) as time out 
Mr.abc xyz| 4/12/13           | 1:30 Pm                              | 3:30Pm
```

i have tried this but not getting the required result:-

```
SELECT u.[username], 
       c.[clockinclockouttypeid], 
       c.[createddate] 
FROM   [Paramount].[dbo].[clockinclockout] AS c 
       JOIN [Paramount].[dbo].[userprofile] AS u 
         ON c.userid = u.[userid] 
WHERE  c.[clockinclockouttypeid] = 1 

SELECT u.[username], 
       c.[clockinclockouttypeid], 
       c.[createddate] 
FROM   [Paramount].[dbo].[clockinclockout] AS c 
       JOIN [Paramount].[dbo].[userprofile] AS u 
         ON c.userid = u.[userid] 
WHERE  c.[clockinclockouttypeid] = 2 rProfile] as u on c.UserId = u.[UserId] where c.[ClockInClockOutTypeId]=2
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks for editing Chaudhari Saab ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try UNION like this

```
select [UserName], MAX([Date]) as [Date], MAX(InTime) as InTime, MAX(OutTime) as OutTime
FROM (
    select u.[UserName],
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), c.[CreatedDate], 101) as [Date],
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), c.[CreatedDate], 108) as InTime,
           null as OutTime
    from [ClockInClockOut] as c 
    inner join [UserProfile] as u on c.UserId = u.[UserId] 
    where c.[ClockInClockOutTypeId]=1 

    UNION 
    select u.[UserName],
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), c.[CreatedDate], 101)  as [Date],
           null as InTime,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), c.[CreatedDate], 108)as OutTime
    from [ClockInClockOut] as c 
    inner join [UserProfile] as u on c.UserId = u.[UserId] 
    where c.[ClockInClockOutTypeId]=2
) tt
GROUP BY [UserName]
```

**[SQL Demo 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3c58/1)**

**Update :**

You can also use CASE WHEN like below :

```
select [UserName], MAX([Date]) as [Date], MAX(InTime) as InTime, MAX(OutTime) as OutTime
FROM
(
   select u.[UserName],
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), c.[CreatedDate], 101) as [Date],
          CASE WHEN c.[ClockInClockOutTypeId]=1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), c.[CreatedDate], 108) ELSE null END as InTime,
          CASE WHEN c.[ClockInClockOutTypeId]=2 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), c.[CreatedDate], 108) ELSE null END as OutTime
   from [ClockInClockOut] as c 
   inner join [UserProfile] as u on c.UserId = u.[UserId] 
) tt
GROUP BY [UserName]
```

**[SQL Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3c58/3)**

Comment: you are just simply great man...thanks a lot Upendra Chaudhari ...you saved my lots of time ..thanks man..;)

Comment: than you very much chaudhari saab..keep it up this awesome work...god bless you